# Pandas add space between characters if necessary

Tags: python, regex, pandas

How can I add a space so that row **2** has a space between the "PEO - word"? Regex always confuses me, is there a good way to learn? Many of the values look like row **1** with proper spacing.

```
df 
             Name
1 'PEO - word word, LLC - Austria - 1 EE'
2 'PEO-aword-9EE - RB'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try using `str.replace` as follows:

```
df["Name"] = df["Name"].str.replace("(\w)\s*-\s*(\w)", "\\1 - \\2")
```

For the input:

```
PEO-aword-9EE - RB
```

the output would be:

```
PEO - aword - 9EE - RB
```

Comment: @Bigmoose70 By answering questions like this on Stack Overflow `:-)`

Comment: How about this variant? 'PEO_NuveenGlobal_1EE in South Korea - RB'

Comment: Variant?  What do you mean by this?

Comment: Actually I figured it out I am going to just replace '_' with '-' then run the regex code!